# How to use Typekit on MailChimp archive pages

Tags: mailchimp

Can someone help me figure out how to use Typekit fonts on MailChimp newsletter Archive pages? I know you can set *allowed* domains, and I've determined that my newsletter Archive pages are served from *http://us6.campaign-archive1.com/* and *http://us5.campaign-archive2.com/*, so based on Typekit's instructions I've set the allowed domains to:

`*.campaign-archive1.com,*.campaign-archive2.com`

But it's still not working — yes I have my script's in place and my CSS set because it's working on `localhost`, just not MailChimp's Archive pages.

Can someone help?

Comment: Did you figure this out, I don't think it's possible to use Typekit for mailchimp.

Comment: Nah, unfortunately I don't think it is. There may be a way if I can determine the IP address that serves the archives, but I haven't tried yet and my gut is telling me no.